# Where to ask tool/API/technology selection questions

Tags: discussion

I tried to ask on Stack Overflow for a tool or technology choice, and my question was closed as non-constructive or not intended for Stack Overflow. I tried to ask the same question on *[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and it was closed with the same reasoning.

I see that those types of questions usually have a lot of up-votes, but they are typically closed quickly. So, there exists a need for a forum where people can discuss which technology/[API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)/tool to use, but I haven't found something like that yet.

Is there a place like that within the Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: There are a number of questions to the right -->. The answer to all of them, I'm sorry, is nowhere. These questions are not suitable for anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: http://www.slant.co/ perhaps?

Comment: See also: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the subject matter; it's the nature of the question itself.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  It says:

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

However, it also says

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam.  Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

The link provided points to an article that goes into great detail about why these questions are generally unsuitable for any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Well, I understand the potential problems, it's just sometimes you spend so much time and effort to even find out possible options, let's say someone is shopping for a tool, and Google search is usually pretty bad answer, there is a bunch of SEO stuff there and the answers are even more opinionated or just plain (but not obvious) advertisement. With the votes here at least you can identify the most popular tool at the moment.

Comment: http://slant.co is better for that, especially if all you care about is popularity.