# Where to ask - Video Subscription Platform

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Hello where can I ask this question?**

> I've a customer that wants a web platform with a monthly(or other
> term) subscription plan to provide gym/fitness videos and a few
> articles.
>
> I started by building a video platform from scratch with the following
> tech stack
>
> PHP/Symfony CloudFlare Video Hosting Symfony EasyAdmin as backend
> However, I don't feel it is the best approach for this. I believe
> there are tons of platforms that can do this much better than I do.
>
> I found a few, however, almost all of them have already implemented
> payment solutions. This is not bad, however, I'd like to integrate
> this platform with a Portuguese (yes I'm Portuguese) payment provider.
> This is an easy API integration that I can implement if the platform
> provides some kind of integration.
>
> Do you know any platform, library, software that I can use to
> implement this? I've no preference on the stack at all, I just want
> something that works and I can customize to my customer needs, which
> are not many, just a Portuguese payment provider.

Comment: Why is this closed as a duplicate when the duplicates are so old (over 6 years) **and** do not mention the only site where asking for software is one topic? The software recs help says "This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”. While this includes software libraries for development use, ". The question could easily be rewritten to be on topic there.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for

> any platform, library, software that I can use to implement this

will be off topic on all the SE technical sites as far as I know, except for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

However, they have very strict requirements for questions they accept.

If you are going to post there, please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Related: [Where to ask tool/API/technology selection questions - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215173/where-to-ask-tool-api-technology-selection-questions)